# RedisCommandExecutionException in Java Lettuce Redis client

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I have a problem with a Java [Lettuce](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core) Redis client with ACL: I get an `io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair or user is disabled` exception.
I have a Redis Docker container configured as follows:

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM redis:6.2.1

COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
COPY users.acl /etc/redis/users.acl

EXPOSE 6379

CMD ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
```

The `redis.conf` file is:

```
aclfile /etc/redis/users.acl
```

and the `users.acl` file is:

```
user myuser on +@all ~* >mypassword
user default off
```

I run the container with the command:

```
docker run -it -p 6379:6379 --name myredis myredis
```

My Java client is:

```
...

import io.lettuce.core.RedisClient;
import io.lettuce.core.api.StatefulRedisConnection;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        try {
            RedisClient redisClient = RedisClient.create("redis://myuser:mypassword@localhost");
            StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> connection = redisClient.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected to Redis");
            connection.close();
            redisClient.shutdown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("End!");
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run it, I get the error:

```
io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost:6379
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:78)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56)
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:234)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:207)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:192)
    at [MY_PACKAGE].Main.main(Main.java:16)
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair or user is disabled.
    at io.lettuce.core.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:135)
    at io.lettuce.core.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:108)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.completeResult(AsyncCommand.java:120)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.complete(AsyncCommand.java:111)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.complete(CommandHandler.java:654)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:614)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.channelRead(CommandHandler.java:565)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1050)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lettuce version: `5.2.1`. Trying to upgrade to `6.1.0`, I get the error: `io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: NOPERM this user has no permissions to run the 'hello' command or its subcommand`, which I cannot understand, since to me it seems that the user has permission for all commands: `"commands" => "+@all"`.

Comment: It seems that the same exact client is able to connect to the Redis instance as soon as I remove the `user default off` line in `users.acl` (re-building the Docker image and launching a new container). Does someone know what's happening here? Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me (lettuce 6.0.4), but it's pure magic:

change

```
user default off
```

into

```
user default off -@all +hello
```

I read redis and lettuce docs but couldn't find a proper explanation, but this may sound more legit to you:

```
user default on nopass -@all +hello
```

which will enable the clients to use default user to run only hello command, then by some means, the clients would know to use the configured user (`myuser`) for further commands.

hope this help, wait for the explanation from everyone :penguin:

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm going to try this ASAP.